# Trying to replace {varN} in a string with actual values

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
s = ExternalLibrary::get_string_data
# ====> my_string_{var1}___{var2}
```

I want to replace "var1" and "var2". This doesn't work:

```
s % {var1: "aa", var2: "bb"}
# ====> my_string_{var1}___{var2}
```

Comment: Nattemando, what you are trying to do is called string interpolation, you should google search: "string interpolation ruby". Here you have a nice example: http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html

Comment: @Nattemando Please take others answers and comments in to consideration. Rather than replying with "gibberish" or "you lack an understanding", perhaps phrase your question better or ask for more information.

Comment: @Nattemando Then you leave me no option other than to report you. SO is a place to get answers and comments for your question. You can't simply try and belittle others for trying to help.

Comment: @sawa there's no question

Answer (score 0):

One option, if I get the point:

```
s = "my_string_{var1}___{var2}"

substitute = {var1: "aa", var2: "bb"}

s.split(/\{(.*?)\}/).map { |e| substitute[e.to_sym] || e }.join

#=> "my_string_aa___bb"
```

Comment: It uses regex to split the original string, then maps the resulting array by the substitution hash, finally joins the array back into a string. Is this "my_string_aa___bb" the desired output?  In case I could edit with a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses `%{`, not `{` for interpolation from hash:

```
s.gsub("{", "%{") % { var1: "foo", var2: "bar" }
# => "my_string_foo___bar"
```